# C # problems with SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I came across the following error, can anyone help me ?

[image]

Comment: Remove the `new`, you're not creating a new object.

Comment: Additionally you're missing a ")" in your query. And your identifiers are in a weird language instead of the standard English.

Comment: don't post the screenshot...post the code instead

Answer (score 0):

Other than what being commented is right absolutely that in your query you are missing the end `)` the below line is totally wrong in your code. It just should be `cmd.ExecuteReader()` since `ExecuteReader()` returns a `reader` object which you need to iterate through to get all the data.

```
SqlDataReader registro = new cmd.ExecuteReader();
```